# Reload menu bar from terminal (not SystemUIServer)

Tags: terminal, menu-bar

I am looking for a way to reload/refresh the "apple symbol" menu in the upper left corner from the terminal.

Searching for ways to refresh the menu has only led me to find the command

```
killall -KILL SystemUIServer
```

this only reload the "widgets" on the right side of the menu and not the content on the left.

I am looking for a way to do this since I have emptied the "recent files" menu programatically (by removing the info from the `com.apple.recentitems.plist` file with `defaults delete com.apple.recentitems RecentDocuments`) but it doesn't show up. (I know that it is possible to turn off the recent files menu completly but that is not what I want).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I finally found a solution to this.

I compiled the following Objective-c code and call it through the terminal.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

  @autoreleasepool {
    LSSharedFileListRef recentDocsList = LSSharedFileListCreate(NULL, kLSSharedFileListRecentDocumentItems, NULL);
    LSSharedFileListRemoveAllItems(recentDocsList);
    NSLog(@"Cleared files!");
  }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you share your method of compilation?  or perhaps link to a downloadable version?